# Substitute to `foreach` for individual array values php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

This is the current code setup I have which you see prints out each value in a table cell.

```
foreach($LS::getClan() as $member) { 
    echo "<tr><td><label class='label label-danger'>{$member['rank']} | <span>{$member['level']}</span></label></td><td>{$member['username']}</td><td>{$member['donated']}</td><td>{$member['received']} </td></tr>"; 
}
```

I don't really know how to explain it but. Uhhhh what I want is to use this for an individual value since this only works best for multiple values. E.g:

```
if ($LS::getClan()['username']) {
    // So this code does not work.
    // I hope you guys are seeing what I want cause I don't really know how to explain it.
    // As you can see $LS::getClan()['username'] does not work as for $members['username'] it works just fine and returns the proper value.
}
```

***So this code does not work. I hope you guys are seeing what I want cause I don't really know how to explain it. As you can see `$LS::getClan()['username']` does not work as for `$members['username']` it works just fine and returns the proper value.***

Dunno what it is called so sorry if my question does not explain it properly/unclear. You can tell me how to revise it though.

Also one last thing feel free to leave me any good references that you guys have in mind. I will gladly read through it and learn a lot from it. :)

NOTE: I think the right/proper question is: How do I make the $member or something work individually and just get rid of the foreach loop altogether.

Comment: because its a multi leveled array, `$member` is another batch of an array

Comment: @GHost So how do I replicate $member to make it like seperate it from the foreach loop. And still work.

Comment: just dereference index zero and the username, you'll access the first batch

Comment: sure no prob, the answer below should suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PHP 5.4 you can just do `echo $LS::getClan()[0]["username"];` ([ref](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-102))

**Example:**

```
class LS {
    private static $array = array(array("username" => "Mike", "rank" => 10),array("username" => "Bob", "rank" => 9));
    public static function getClan() {
        return self::$array;    
    }
}

$LS = 'LS';
foreach($LS::getClan() as $member) { 
    echo $member["username"] . " " . $member["rank"] . "<br>".PHP_EOL;
}

echo $LS::getClan()[0]["username"];
```

> Mike 10
>   Bob 9
>   Mike

Comment: Nice! Just what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

`$LS::getClan()` appears to return an array of members, consider the following example

> sample.php

```
/**
 * list of clan members
 */
$clanMembers = [
    [
        'username' => 'ninjaDude',
        'rank' => 1,
        'level' => 27,
        'donated' => 77,
        'received' => 55
    ],
    [
        'username' => 'rabbitKiller',
        'rank' => 2,
        'level' => 12,
        'donated' => 555,
        'received' => 22
    ],
    [
        'username' => 'bunnyLover',
        'rank' => 3,
        'level' => 11,
        'donated' => 41,
        'received' => 66
    ]
];

foreach($clanMembers as $member) {
    echo "<tr><td><label class='label label-danger'>{$member['rank']} | <span>{$member['level']}</span></label></td><td>{$member['username']}</td><td>{$member['donated']}</td><td>{$member['received']} </td></tr>" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

> output

```
<tr><td><label class='label label-danger'>1 | <span>27</span></label></td><td>ninjaDude</td><td>77</td><td>55 </td></tr>
<tr><td><label class='label label-danger'>2 | <span>12</span></label></td><td>rabbitKiller</td><td>555</td><td>22 </td></tr>
<tr><td><label class='label label-danger'>3 | <span>11</span></label></td><td>bunnyLover</td><td>41</td><td>66 </td></tr>
```

> access a specific element in the array

```
/**
  * this will pick the third member in the array, 
  * this is because the count starts at zero
  */
$member = $clanMembers[2];

echo "<tr><td><label class='label label-danger'>{$member['rank']} | <span>{$member['level']}</span></label></td><td>{$member['username']}</td><td>{$member['donated']}</td><td>{$member['received']} </td></tr>" . PHP_EOL;
```

> output

```
<tr><td><label class='label label-danger'>3 | <span>11</span></label></td><td>bunnyLover</td><td>41</td><td>66 </td></tr>
```